# What is the maximum amount of ancestry feats you may gain?

Tags: feats, optimization, pathfinder-2e

After looking at the rules I noticed that one gets 5 ancestry feats due to level.
Then I noticed a single feat that also gives you an additional ancestry feat (an additional 1st level 1).

My question: is 6 the maximum, or am I overlooking other ways to get additional ancestry feats?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The new maximum is 8.

If we look at the [Dwarf Ancestry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?Traits=54), it says:

> At 1st level, you gain one ancestry feat, and you gain an additional ancestry feat every 4 levels thereafter (at 5th, 9th, 13th, and 17th levels). As a dwarf, you select from among the following ancestry feats.

The other ancestries have similar language for their feat section, this means that you normally only gain 5 ancestry through levels 1-20 (1,5,9,13,17). [Ancestral Paragon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=753) grants you a 6th.

By taking [Oracle](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=14) as our class and choosing the [Ancestors](https://2e.aonprd.com/Mysteries.aspx?ID=1) mystery, we gain an additional ancestry feat at 1st level, and another at level 11 for a grand total of 8.

---

<sup>Note: This is a new version of the answer, for the original answer, you can see it [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/154585/revisions/154585/4). This update was compiled easily due to information from [Wagner Vinhas](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/71437/wagner-vinhas)'s [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/185717/47188).</sup>

<sup>Note for the community: If this answer becomes incorrect due to the release of new content published by paizo, feel free to update the answer accordingly.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Oracles with [Ancestors Mystery](https://2e.aonprd.com/Mysteries.aspx?ID=1) also gain an additional ancestry feat at 1st level and another additional ancestry feat at 11th level. These feats can't be ones that grant physiological effects, such as additional senses or unarmed attacks.